# How to prove that $\xi:\Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{C}$ here has range in the unit circle?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I want to solve the following:

> **Problem.** Suppose $\xi:(\Bbb{R}, +)\to (\Bbb{C}^{\ast},\cdot)$ be a group homomorphism such that
> $\{|\xi(r)|: r\in \Bbb{R}\}$ is a bounded set of *positive* numbers dominated by $1$. Then $|\xi(r)|=1$ for all $r\in \Bbb{R}$.

**Attempt** For an $r$,  I can see that $\xi(nr)= \xi(r)^n$ for all $n \in \Bbb{N}$. So if $|\xi(r)|<1$ then $(0<)|\xi(nr)|=|\xi(r)|^n\to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. Now I am clueless; I didn't get any contradiction. Any hint to proceed.

**Edit.** As pointed in the comments:
We see that for an $r$, $\xi(r)\xi(-r)= \xi(r-r)=\xi(0)=1$ and $\xi(r)\ne0$ as given. Hence for any $r, \xi(-r)=\xi(r)^{-1}$. This implies that $ |\xi(-nr)|=|\xi(r)|^{-n}$ for all $n \in \Bbb{N}$. This will contradict the "boundedness" if $|\xi(r)|<1$.

Comment: Can you extend your result to $n\in \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @JamieRadcliffe Yes, since $\xi(1)\xi(-1)=\xi(1-1)=\xi(0)=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $r \in \mathbb R$.  We know that $|\xi(r)|$ and $|\xi(-r)|$ are both $\leq 1$.  Also,

$$\xi(r) = \xi(-r)^{-1}$$

and hence $|\xi(r)| \geq 1$, being the multiplicative inverse of a number in the range $(0,1]$.  Hence $|\xi(r)| = 1$.